# Combine three (3) queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I would like to combine these three queries into one query:

```
SELECT County, Result1, COUNT(Result1) AS Result1Total
FROM MainData
WHERE (((Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2020' AND '01/30/2020'))
GROUP BY County, Result1
ORDER BY County;

SELECT County, Result2, COUNT(Result2) AS Result2Total
FROM MainData
WHERE (((Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2020' AND '01/30/2020'))
  AND Result2 <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY County, Result2
ORDER BY County;

SELECT County, Result3, COUNT(Result3) AS Result3Total
FROM MainData
WHERE (((Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2020' AND '01/30/2020'))
  AND Result3 <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY County, Result3
ORDER BY County;
```

I would like the output to look as follows:

```
County        Result         Totals
-----------------------------------    
Allegany      Car Services     2
Richmond      Car Services     3
Lynchberg     House Services   5
Charlotte     Car Services     12
Charlotte     House Services   2
NorthHampton  Car Serivces     6
NorthHampton  House Services   8
```

Results 1, 2 and 3 are dropdown boxes with the same information.

Comment: First UNION ALL, then GROUP BY.

Comment: We don't know what the results from your 3 queries look like - so hard to advise.

Comment: As @Dale K has said, without sample data this is impossible to advise. Maybe three ctes meets your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Looks like `GROUPING SETS` would come in handy here:**

```sql
SELECT
    County,
    ISNULL(ISNULL(Result1, Result2), Result3) AS Result,
    COUNT(Result1) AS Result1Total
FROM MainData
WHERE (((Date) BETWEEN '01/01/2020' AND '01/30/2020'))
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (County, Result1),
    (County, Result2),
    (County, Result3)
)
ORDER BY County;
```

If the `Result` columns are nullable then you need a more complex expression:

```sql
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(Result1) = 0 THEN Result1
         WHEN GROUPING(Result1) = 0 THEN Result2
         ELSE Result3
    END AS Result,
```

Answer (score 0):

If column totals represents country wise result wise sum of resulttotal then your query will be:

```
select Country, Result, sum(Result1Total) Totals
from (
    SELECT County, Result1 Result, Count(Result1) AS Result1Total
    FROM MainData
    WHERE (((Date) Between '01/01/2020' And '01/30/2020'))
    GROUP BY County, Result1


    union all

    SELECT County, Result2, Count(Result2) AS Result2Total
    FROM MainData
    WHERE (((Date) Between '01/01/2020' And '01/30/2020'))
    AND Result2 <> 'NULL'
    GROUP BY County, Result2

    union all

    SELECT County, Result3, Count(Result3) AS Result3Total
    FROM MainData
    WHERE (((Date) Between '01/01/2020' And '01/30/2020'))
    AND Result3 <> 'NULL'
    GROUP BY County, Result3
)
group by County, Result
ORDER BY County;
```

Comment: I would recommend improving your query layout...

Comment: I would try my level best. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe like I have done? Clearly laid out with indenting...

Comment: I wouldn't attempt an answer without sample data. You may be right, but to me this looks ugly.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks again. I would try to do so.

Comment: `ORDER BY` cannot be used in a subquery

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Charlieface.